# Trying to style an hr tag to have end caps

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to style an hr tag to have end caps like the attached image. While I could just remove the background from that image and set that as background, that won't change width with the page. At the moment, how to get this correctly made is eluding me.

[Image of the desired hr.](https://gyazo.com/a89aafb7a2d6c137a9052e6f111691ae)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. **https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/sfr5kw4e/**

```
hr {
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  position: relative
}

hr::before,
hr::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: black;
  bottom: -4px;
}

hr::before {
  left: 0;
}

hr::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

Think if you really need an `hr` though, instead of a simple `div`

Comment: Ah, I see how that works. The content entry forces the before and after areas to render. Tricky.

Comment: Yep, don't forget your empty `content`!

Comment: Does not seem to work on chrome and android devices. Works on firefox though.

Comment: @iheathers It seems like chrome is applying an `overflow: hidden;` rule on the `hr` element by default. Try setting `overflow: visible;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use before, after pseudo elements. Something like:

```
hr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

See this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMpJXR

Answer (score 0):

Use `before` and `after` pseudo classes:

[image]

Key to styling an `<hr>` is also to replace the embossed line with a border. The round endcaps are done by rendering `before` and `after` blocks with a `border-radius` that makes them circles:

```
hr {
    border: 0 solid black;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
hr:before, hr:after {
    content: " ";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    }
hr:before {
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
}
hr:after {
    bottom: -4px;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Here's a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/codifekiyi/edit?html,css,output)